# MultiIndex Pandas From Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How would I take a df like this:

```
Dates          Type           1      2      3                                                                                                                            ...
2018-01-01     Type1        Golf    Van    Jeep
2018-01-02     Type1        Golf    Van    Jeep
2018-01-01     Type2        Golf1   Van1   Jeep1
2018-01-02     Type2        Golf2   Van2   Jeep2
```

and turn it into:

```
                               Type1                    Type2
Dates                    1      2      3           1      2      3                                                                                                               ...
2018-01-01            Golf    Van    Jeep      Golf1    Van1    Jeep1
2018-01-02            Golf    Van    Jeep      Golf2    Van2    Jeep2
```

EDIT: 
I would like to introduce a second index like this:

```
Type                          Type1                    Type2
Numbers                  1      2      3           1      2      3    
Dates                                                                                                                              ...
2018-01-01            Golf    Van    Jeep      Golf1    Van1    Jeep1
2018-01-02            Golf    Van    Jeep      Golf2    Van2    Jeep2
```

EDIT:
Now if I wanted to relabel all the Number index values - how would I create this:

```
Type                          Type1                    Type2
Numbers                  p1     p2     p3         p1      p2      p3    
Dates                                                                                                                              ...
2018-01-01            Golf    Van    Jeep      Golf1    Van1    Jeep1
2018-01-02            Golf    Van    Jeep      Golf2    Van2    Jeep2
```

EDIT: 
Can just use: 
`.add_prefix('hh')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), then change order of levels by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and sorting `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Dates','Type']).unstack().swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
Type       Type1             Type2             
               1    2     3      1     2      3
Dates                                          
2018-01-01  Golf  Van  Jeep  Golf1  Van1  Jeep1
2018-01-02  Golf  Van  Jeep  Golf2  Van2  Jeep2
```

EDIT: Add [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) by tuple:

```
df = (df.set_index(['Dates','Type'])
        .unstack()
        .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
        .rename_axis(('Type','Numbers'), axis=1))
print (df)
Type       Type1             Type2             
Numbers        1    2     3      1     2      3
Dates                                          
2018-01-01  Golf  Van  Jeep  Golf1  Van1  Jeep1
2018-01-02  Golf  Van  Jeep  Golf2  Van2  Jeep2
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. How would we add a level below `Type` to name the numbers

Comment: @Bob - Can you show expected output in edited question?

Comment: Thank you, very much all your help :) - If i was to also re-label all the numbers to say p1, p2, p3 .... how would this be done ?

Comment: Ahhh I would just `.add_prefix('pp')`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `melt` then `pivot` it back

```
s=df.melt(['Dates','Type']).pivot_table(index=['Dates'],columns=['Type','variable'],values=['value'],aggfunc='sum')
s.columns=s.columns.droplevel(level=0)
s
Out[189]: 
Type       Type1             Type2             
variable       1    2     3      1     2      3
Dates                                          
2018-01-01  Golf  Van  Jeep  Golf1  Van1  Jeep1
2018-01-02  Golf  Van  Jeep  Golf2  Van2  Jeep2
```